# How to make password with mnemonic words?

Tags: bip39, passphrase, mnemonic

i'm new on blockchain development and i'm trying to make a login like metamask in vuejs. Can someone teach me how to make 13 mnemonics word, where the last mnemonic is the password value get from an input using bip39?

```
            async createWallet(){
        const mnemonic = await generateMnemonic();
        // const entropy = await entropyToMnemonic();
        // this.passphraseCreated = entropy

        if(this.selectLang == 'english'){
             this.mnemonic = await setDefaultWordlist('english') 
        } else if (this.selectLang == 'chinese'){
             this.mnemonic = await setDefaultWordlist('chinese_traditional') 
        }

        const seed = await mnemonicToSeed(this.mnemonic, this.createPassword || "");
        const root = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed);
        const masterPrivateKey = root.privateKey.toString('hex');

        const addrNode = root.derive("m/44'/60'/0'/0/0");
        const pubKey = privateToPublic(addrNode._privateKey);
        const addr = publicToAddress(pubKey).toString('hex');
        const address = toChecksumAddress(addr);

        console.log(mnemonic)

    async login() {

        const seed = await mnemonicToSeed(this.mnWrited, this.passLogin || "")

        if(validateMnemonic(this.mnWrited || this.passLogin))
        {
            const root = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed)
            const addrNode = root.derive("m/44'/60'/0'/0/0")
            const pubKey = privateToPublic(addrNode._privateKey)
            const addr = publicToAddress(pubKey).toString('hex')
            const address = toChecksumAddress(addr)
            this.address = address

            console.log(address)
            fetch('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=' + address + '&tag=latest&apikey=R5AABKRFH5HMXBA9IBQ5G44HS84B8YJWFI')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                if(response.status == '0'){
                    // console.log(response.message)
                    // this.logged = true;
                }
                else {
                    // console.log(response)
                    this.logged = true;
                }
            })
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log("Wrong Words")
            this.showResponse = true;
        }

        // if(this.mnWrited.length < 12 && this.mnWrited.length > 12){
        //     console.log('Digite as 12 palavras.')
        // }
    },
```

Comment: The function `mnemonicToSeed` from bip39 accept an optional password as second parameter. Your code seems to already use it. What is your problem?

Comment: When i try to login, he doesen't recognize the password as valid. I Updated my question with the login code.

Comment: Sorry, but without a small reproducible example is impossible to say what is wrong.

Comment: I edited post and put an async login () function